# Books on meta-cognition that would be relevant for those involved in mathematics?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, meta-cognition

In 1992 [Schoenfeld wrote an excellent "review"](http://hplengr.engr.wisc.edu/Math_Schoenfeld.pdf) of (among other things) metacognition as it applies to mathematics: whether from the perspective of a student, or a teacher.

Metacognition, as quoted by Schoenfeld from Flavell, is:

> Metacognition refers to one's knowledge concerning one's own cognitive
>   processes or anything related to them...

In Schoenfeld's lengthy review, the sections most relevant to metacognition are:

- Self-regulation, or monitoring and control (pg. 57 of [this](http://hplengr.engr.wisc.edu/Math_Schoenfeld.pdf))
- Beliefs and affects (pg. 67 of [this](http://hplengr.engr.wisc.edu/Math_Schoenfeld.pdf))
- Teacher beliefs (pg.71 of [this](http://hplengr.engr.wisc.edu/Math_Schoenfeld.pdf))
- Societal beliefs (pg. 73 of [this](http://hplengr.engr.wisc.edu/Math_Schoenfeld.pdf))
- Practices (pg. 74 of [this](http://hplengr.engr.wisc.edu/Math_Schoenfeld.pdf))

1992 was a long while back. What are some newer resources that talk about metacognition? One book I can think of is [A mind for numbers, by Barbara Oakley](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/039916524X). Any other recommendations?

Comment: Have you read Schoenfeld's more recent book, *How We Think*? Also, I assume you are asking for specific recommendations, but a general search of google books has some nice returns: [**2010-2015**](https://www.google.com/search?q=metacognition+schoenfeld&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2010%2Ccd_max%3A2015&tbm=bks).

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Yes, I am looking for specific recommendations by people who have read or made use of the books they are recommending.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman P.S. I had not heard of Schoenfeld's book! Would you like to write up an answer?

Comment: I'm finally going through Schoenfeld's book now; if still desirable, i could try to write up an answer drawing from it (once I'm through reading/digesting!). Let me know...

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Always desirable :) Please do write something up!

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I second user89's encouragement to provide a write-up.

Comment: Possibly relevant post: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10939/is-metacognition-ever-bad